# Tkinter Focusout Entry Validation

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

I have seen several questions on tkinter entry validation here but each one seems to stick to `validate="key"` option.

While this is great for interactive validation, what i want is a `"focusout"` validation.

More particularly I am looking to validate an email field. Here's the code I have tried so far but it doesn't work.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import re

master = tk.Tk()

def validateEmail(P):
    x = re.match(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", P)
    return (x != None)

vcmd = (master.register(validateEmail), '%P')
emailentry = tk.Entry(master, validate="focusout", validatecommand=vcmd)
emailentry.pack()

b = tk.Button(master, text="Login")
b.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Any ideas on how to validate email entry please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%S` represents the string being inserted, if any. This is only meaningful for validation on text insertion. When the widget loses focus, no character is being inserted so this parameter will always be an empty string. Since it is an empty string, it will always fail your validation.

You should use `%P` instead, which represents the whole string.

Also, strictly speaking, the validation function should return a boolean rather than an object. You should save the result of the match in a variable, then return something like `return (match is not None)`

Comment: thanks i have modified the code in question to reflect your suggestions. Now it returns true or false based on whether it is valid email or not. But then if the return value is false, shouldn't it highlight or delete the text in entry widget ? It does nothing to that effect.

Comment: thankyou got it - needed to define 'invcmd' to handle False return

Comment: @QuakiGabbar: yes, if it's invalid you'll probably need to do some extra work such as forcing focus back to the entry widget, displaying an error message, etc.